# iOS Developer Enterprise program - can device users install the app directly?

Tags: ios

I wish to enrol in the iOS Developer Enterprise program. I cannot find an answer to my question - and for that matter Apple themselves aren't sure when I ask on the phone.

My question: can I deliver an app over-the-air directly to the target device, if that app is developed using the **iOS Developer Enterprise program**?

Ideally this is the case, and I can deliver the app to "road warrior" colleagues who do not wish to open a laptop and start iTunes to install an app on their iOS device (almost always an iPhone).

What is your experience?

Answer (score 3):

This is possible. We are doing the same thing in the company I work in.
We put .ipa and .plist file on the server and provide link to .plist file. When user clicks on the link from their mobile device they are prompted to install application.

The only necessary thing is to include UDIDs of all devices to the provisioning profile with which you are signing your application.

This is the content of the .plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://location of your .ipa file</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>your.app.identifier</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>3.5.2</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>app_title</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And then add link to your plist file:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://location-of-plist.plist">
Download application</a>
```

Comment: I think, here is limit for number of devices you register per licence.

Comment: Yes, 100 devices per licence.

Answer (score 1):

> I think, here is limit for number of devices you register per licence. –  preetam Aug 16 at 12:46
>
> Yes, 100 devices per licence. –  JPetric Aug 16 at 13:04

iOS Developer Enterprise program allow you to distribute "In-House" apps to unlimited number of devices. There is no such 100 devices limitation.

Comment: I couldn't find any official doc that says the "In-House" distribution is unlimited, pls share the apple link if you find any, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [Distributing Enterprise Apps for iOS Devices: About deploying apps](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/#app43ad83f9) (which requires Apple developer login) it describes 4 different ways of distributing Apps including over the air:

1. Distribute the app for your users to install using iTunes.
2. Have an IT administrator install the app on devices using iPhone Configuration Utility or Apple Configurator.
3. **Post the app on a secure web server; users access and perform the installation wirelessly.**
4. Use your MDM server to instruct managed devices to install an in-house or App Store app, if your MDM server supports it.